How to prove for $AX=B$ , number of linearly independent columns in B can't exceed A?
I want a way to prove that for matrices $A(n \times m)$, $X(m \times n)$ and $B(n \times n)$ such that $AX=B$ and the number of linearly independent columns $k$ in $A$ with $k<n$, the maximum number of linearly independent columns in $B$ can't be more than $k$ for any such possible matrices.
EDIT: An intutive and less formal proof will also suffice.

Directly in terms of matrices, you can write down the definition of matrix multiplication and see that every column of $B$ is a linear combination of columns of $A$, which implies the result.
